# Vite Build Error: Unable to Resolve CSS Import Path on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, vite

While running yarn build in my Ubuntu environment, I encountered the following error:

```scss
transforming (211) node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/lib/utils/uuid.jsUnable to resolve `@import "./textbookList.css"` from /home/user-name/myproject/src/assets/css/pages/myModule
✓ 217 modules transformed.
✓ built in 8.49s
[vite:css] [postcss] ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/user-name/myproject/myModuleCSS.css'
file: /home/user-name/myproject/src/assets/css/index.css:undefined:undefined
error during build:
Error: [postcss] ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/user-name/myproject/myModuleCSS.css'
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The TypeScript compilation (`tsc`) passes without any issues. However, during the Vite build process, the usage of "./*" seems to be interpreted as an import from the project root directory. The problematic CSS contents are:

```css
@import "./myModuleCSS.css";
@import "./myModuleCSS2.css";
```

My vite.config.ts looks like:

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import { createUnplugin } from "unplugin";

const unplugin = createUnplugin((mode: string) => {
  return {
    name: "unplugin-fixenv",
    transform(code) {
      if (code.includes("process.env.NODE_ENV")) {
        return code.replace(/_globalThis\$process\.env\.NODE_ENV/, `"${mode}"`);
      }
      return code;
    },
  };
});

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({ mode }: { mode: string }) => {
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };
  return defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), svgr(), tsconfigPaths(), unplugin.vite("development")],
    server: {
      port: 3000,
    },
    define: {
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(mode),
    },
  });
};
```

The settings in my tsconfig.json are as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "typeRoots": ["./@types ", "./node_modules/@types"],

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src", "svg.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "public"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu version 20.04. My package.json dependencies are:

```json
...
"dependencies": {
    "@toast-ui/react-calendar": "^2.1.3",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "interactjs": "^1.10.18",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-calendar": "^4.6.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.13.0",
    "react-slider": "^2.0.6",
    "react-week-calendar": "^0.1.3",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
    "@types/react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-slider": "^1.3.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "daisyui": "3.1.7",
    "msw": "1.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "postcss-nested": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss-nesting": "^11.2.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "unplugin": "^1.3.1",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^3.2.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0"
  },
...
```